# How to fix Itunes having changed podcast name to "Podcast Error"

Tags: itunes, podcasts, itunes-11

I am using Itunes 11.0.2.26 on a Dell Latitude D531 laptop running Windows XP Home.  In the middle of a session using Itunes a few days ago I noticed that in my Itunes library the NPR Fresh Air podcast had been renamed as "Podcast Error" and all of the subscribed podcast entries (in my library) that had not been downloaded to my computer's hard drive had disappeared.  The only podcasts that are listed are those that I've downloaded.

I have several other podcasts that I subscribe to; they appear normal in my itunes library.

I've subscribed to the NPR Fresh Air podcast since some time in 2009 and have been manually selecting ones to download to my computer's hard drive during all that time (through numerous updates to Itunes).

It is likely that I could fix this by following the advice in "http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2562" which is entitled "Podcasts playlist in iTunes
is empty" (or similar such advice that can be found on the Internet).  My question is twofold: What caused this to happen?  Is there a more subtle fix for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the "Refresh" button in the list view of the podcast "Podcast Error" restored the proper name of the podcast and gave me a list of new episodes that I could download.  Still missing were listings of older episodes that I haven't downloaded.  [Way to get old podcasts in iTunes](https://superuser.com/questions/11006/way-to-get-old-podcasts-in-itunes) gave several prescriptions for getting those listed (e.g. Shift-click on podcast arrow in list view).  Also, the context menu (right click) for a podcast in the list offers "Show all available episodes", which probably would have worked as well.